# python aws s3: downloading files based on size

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I can filter files in an s3 bucket based on file size, and I can download files, but I get an error trying to do both. This is Python 3.4.

```
import boto3
import re

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
some_file = "whatever.txt"

for file in bucket.objects.all():
    if file.size < 1000 and re.search(".*txt$", file.key):
        print(file.key, file.size)
        bucket.download_file(file.key, file.key)

bucket.download_file(some_file, some_file) # this works fine
```

The above for loop works to get files less than 1000 bytes and are .txt files. But the bucket.download_file (file.key, file.key) part gives me this:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

However, the last line works fine. What's the difference?

FYI, I searched for the error and I saw some stuff about the access permissions. This bucket is not public access. I'm running from an EMR cluster and the secret key credentials are already defined so I don't need to specify in the script.

UPDATE: the full error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_size.py", line 39, in <module>
    bucket.download_file(file.key, file.key)
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3-1.9.189-py3.4.egg/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 246, in bucket_download_file
    ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3-1.9.189-py3.4.egg/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 172, in download_file
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3-1.9.189-py3.4.egg/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
    future.result()
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/s3transfer-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/s3transfer-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/s3transfer-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/s3transfer-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/s3transfer/download.py", line 345, in _submit
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore-1.12.189-py3.4.egg/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/hadoop/jobs/scripts/s3/python34/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore-1.12.189-py3.4.egg/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: What does file.key print out?

Comment: In which line this exception raised?

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen print(file.key, file.size) prints out like this:
file_one.txt 44
file_two.txt 30

Comment: @ErHarshRathore the exception is raised by the line bucket.download_file(file.key, file.key)

Comment: can you paste full error stack here.

Comment: @ErHarshRathore I updated the post with the full error. Thanks.

Comment: try to write the error line like **bucket.download_file('hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')** or **bucket.download_file(file.key,"/tmp/"+file.key)** because download_from and download_to file should not be same.

Comment: The error is saying that you do not have access to the object, or possibly that the object does not exist. Look at the `file.key` for the object that fails, then check the permissions for that object. You can test it by specifically trying to do: `bucket.download_file(file.key, '/tmp/testfile')`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input, but it turned out to be some weird permissions I had on a few of the files in this bucket that I didn't realize. The code as above works on the current bucket after removing them and also on other buckets.

I can confirm this part works:

```
bucket.download_file(file.key, file.key)
```